# Atribuir um valor a uma variável quando o retorno da busca seja NULL

Tags: php

Estou tentando atribuir um valor a uma variável quando o retorno da busca seja `NULL`, mas não estou conseguindo, quando verifico o valor da variável `$IdSetor` ela está `NULL` e não zero, como preciso.

A pesquisa e o que estou tentando fazer:

```
// BUSCANDO IdSetor
$sqlVerSetor = "SELECT IdSetor FROM cadSetor WHERE IdSetorOld = ?";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlVerSetor);
// DEFINE O TIPO DA VARIÁVEL INT OU STR
$stm->bindValue(1, $LotacaoRH, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
$stm->execute();    
$ResDadosSetor = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
// CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
$conSqlRegSetor = count($ResDadosSetor);            
// FECHANDO A CONSULTA
$stm->closeCursor(); 

foreach($ResDadosSetor as $RegSetor) {  

    $IdSetor = $RegSetor->IdSetor;                  

    if ($IdSetor == NULL) {
        $IdSetor = 0;
    } else {
        $IdSetor = $IdSetor;
    }   
}
```

Vou colocar uma imagem da minha consulta, mesmo com as dicas dadas ainda não consegui fazer o que preciso, mas esqueci de mencionar que a minha consulta gera um conjunto de registros vazio, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função **[is_null()](http://www.php.net/is_null)**, que retorna `true` se a variável for `null`:

```
if (is_null($IdSetor)) {
   $IdSetor = 0;
} else {

    // O valor não é null
    // fazer algo aqui

}
```

Esse `else` seria desnecessário. Atribuir a si mesmo o próprio valor é redundância. Mas você pode usar o `else` para outra ação caso o valor não seja `null`.

Comment: Esse `else` é realmente necessário? hehe

Comment: rsrs... tinha nem notado

Comment: @dvd, se a retorno não for null preciso gravar o valor retornado.

Comment: @adventistapr Vc não queria atribuir 0 ao $IdSetor se fosse null?

Comment: @adventistapr Atualizei a resposta. Veja se era isso que queria.

Comment: Isso mesmo @dvd, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção é utilizar o operador identico `===` na hora de comparar os valores.

```
$IdSetor = ($IdSetor === null) ? 0 : $IdSetor;
```

Answer (score 3):

Um pouco mais enxuto, sem redundância:

```
if (is_null($IdSetor)) $IdSetor = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

A partir do PHP 7, existe o operador de coalescência nula, que retorna o primeiro operando se este existir e não for nulo, caso contrário, retorna o segundo operando. Neste caso, bastaria fazer:

```
$IdSetor = $IdSetor ?? 0;
```

Se `$IdSetor` for nulo (ou não existir), passará a valer zero.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UPWcxV) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WellgroomedCurvyApplicationsuite)</sup>

Ou, para ficar ainda mais legível, fazer direto:

```
$IdSetor = $RegSetor->IdSetor ?? 0;
```

O que elimina a necessidade de efetuar a verificação posterior.

[Operador de coalescência nula](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: Essa dica foi muito boa.